# Laravel 5.1 authentication not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel 5.1 and getting my head around it I started to build a blog with it. But there comes a problem. My users cannot login after registration.

One thing is that when they register they are automatically signed in but after that (after they have logged out) they can't login again.

The error message appearing is the email field is required. No matter what you put into the email field it still return email field is required.

This is the login form, I'm using the Illuminate/Html package

```
@extends('main')

@section('title')

Login 

@stop

@section('content')

<div class="row">
<h1>Please Login</h1>

<hr>
</div>

{!! Form::open() !!}
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Username:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, [ 'placeholder' => 'Enter your email']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password:') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', null, [ 'placeholder' => 'Enter Password']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        {!! Form::checkbox('remember') !!}
        {!! Form::label('remember', 'Remembe Me') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        {!! Form::submit('Login', [ 'class' => 'expand radius button']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

@if($errors->any())
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <ul class="errors">

            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
{!! Form::close() !!}

 @stop
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: show us the login form

Comment: is that on page error?

Comment: the error produced is from the inbuilt laravel error method

Comment: @GideonAppoh Did you try to use an empty string (`''`) instead of explicitly setting default values of `email` and `password` fields to `null`? Not 100% sure, but something tells me the Form helper does not like `null`s there.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html) `Form::password()` only takes 2 arguments. Remove the `null,` part.

Comment: Need to see your controller that processes this request. Not really sure why no one has asked for it

Answer (score -1):

If u are using authentication
change

```
Form::open()
```

to

```
 {{Form::open(array('url' => 'auth/login', 'method' => 'post'))}}
```